# TastyPie authentication for pure javascript site

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I'm using Django TastyPie for my API. I have a completely separate HTML application that my user views and will see basic read only info from the Django API. My question is what authentication method should I use in this situation. The HTML application is technically me not the user and they don't login. The app is not Django but pure javascript, hiding a key or anything else is pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> will see basic read only info from the Django API.

It sounds like you probably just want to make those bits of the API publicly available for read-only access, and then *not* use any authentication method.

As you say attempting to hide a key isn't a sensible way to go, and if there's no kind of user login then you can't really authenticate in any secure way.